# XCode - unable to create snapshot - don't want git

Tags: xcode, git, snapshot

After several successfully done "create snapshot"s, XCode now tells me it is "unable to create a snapshot" "please tell me who you are"... and some stuff about git.
i never used git and don't want to, but i need to create snapshots...
Do you know how to manage this?

thank you!

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if Xcode now requires git to make snapshots. But this is just an assumption. Why don't you want git?

Comment: i only want to re-/store it locally, so i don't want to use any git server. but it seems like xcode forces me now to...

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/a/13363167/6309 help? Or http://stackoverflow.com/a/12798235/6309?

Comment: Just FYI: You can use git locally if you wish. There is no requirement that you push to a git server.

Comment: okay, maybe i'm fine with using git locally, but do i need to install it? because i thought it is built in Xcode anyway...

Comment: If you've installed the `Command Line Tools`, git should be installed. Otherwise, you may need to install them through `Xcode => Preferences... => Downloads => Components`

Comment: yeaaaaaayyyyy!!! 1000000 thanks to you!! it worked!!